# Keyboard hides edit text

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I have found similar questions about this problem and as I am a beginner, I am unable to figure out why none of the solutions is working for me. I have a TabLayout and each tab holds a fragment. In one fragment, I have an EditText at the middle of the layout and whenever I try to write in the EditText, the keyboard hides half of the EditText. Many suggested adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` in the manifest file but it did not work as the EditText is within a fragment, not an activity (I guess). I yet added it to the manifest file in the mother activity of the tab fragments, did not work. Can anyone suggest me how to handle this? Here is my fragment layout code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    tools:context="com.example.lenovo.memcreator.fragments.CreateMemoryFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/create_a_new_memory"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="8"
            tools:ignore="DisableBaselineAlignment">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:text="@string/memory_name"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/memory_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:textColor="#c2000000"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="8"
            tools:ignore="DisableBaselineAlignment">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="10">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:contentDescription=""
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/no_image"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription,NestedWeights" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_add_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="@string/browse"
                    android:textAllCaps="false" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_capture_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="@string/capture"
                    android:textAllCaps="false" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="@string/post_mem"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/memory_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:minLines="6"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:textColor="#c2000000"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_create_memory"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/create_memory"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here, how it looks before typing: [http://imgur.com/a/IXT7V](https://imgur.com/a/IXT7V)
And while typing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRvGa.jpg

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `ScrollView`, to provide flexibility.

Comment: Instead of FrameLayout?

Comment: try the answer, just copy to your xml and run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this same code with `ScrollView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:paddingTop="15dp"
tools:context="com.example.lenovo.memcreator.fragments.CreateMemoryFragment">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/create_a_new_memory"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="8"
            tools:ignore="DisableBaselineAlignment">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:text="@string/memory_name"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/memory_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:textColor="#c2000000"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="8"
            tools:ignore="DisableBaselineAlignment">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="10">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:contentDescription=""
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/no_image"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription,NestedWeights" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_add_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="@string/browse"
                    android:textAllCaps="false" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_capture_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="@string/capture"
                    android:textAllCaps="false" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="@string/post_mem"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/memory_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:minLines="6"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:textColor="#c2000000"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_create_memory"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/create_memory"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Tried doing it too. Did not work. Thanks for your suggestions though.

Comment: @ArifulHoqueMaruf, what happened when u click, did it scrolled or not ?

Comment: Yes it scrolled. But I want to bring the whole edittext above the keyboard instead of seeing it being half-hidden. Until I get better answer, the answer you provided works good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Only put this in `Manifest` file's 'Activity'

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: Hey @ArifulHoqueMaruf sorry i dont have any other solution its working at my end.If face any  other type of issue  let me know

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your time. :)